# Cannot understand the syntax of background position?

Tags: html, css, gradient

I am learning design patterns using gradients in **CSS3**. But stuck up with something which I cannot able to understand how it works.
Actually, I am trying to understand patterns through the blog post of Lea Verou: [Link](http://24ways.org/2011/css3-patterns-explained/).

Now, there's one pattern i.e., checkbox pattern [CheckBox Pattern Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/1457677).

There is a `background-position: 0 0, 50px 50px;` set in its CSS.

As far as I know we can set top right bottom left inside background position but they are set without **comma** separation.

So, Can anyone explain me how this exactly background-position works what else we can do with background position as this is something new. I only use to set image from CSS Sprites as of earlier but this is something new.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-position: 0 0, 50px 50px;` is setting the value of the position for 2 different backgrounds. If you look at the sample, you will see that `background-image` actually has 2 sets of the same background.